# Decrease the Position left value when user add more content

Tags: html, css

Once User click on text, we are allowing user to edit the text....

when user add more text , the text is moving only to right side as in [Link1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zaSYNM1BiBuWaP243B9lir8j7p7MCvO-/view)

**Requirement** :

but it should move in **both directions** as in this [Link2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OoS1KglALSdDNWHl2LpoeN5SvkulMQBm/view) or in [website](https://www.greetingsisland.com/design/invitations/surrealism-balloons/201-14150)....

**Logic** :

Seems like I need to decrease **value** of **position left** Once user add more text, but how to achieve this ?

```css
.text
{

position:absolute;
left: 500px;
font-size:28px;
}
```

```html
<p contenteditable="true" class ="text">text</p>
```

Comment: I do not believe this is enough of the code you have to reproduce this issue as you noted.  Please edit the question with a minimum viable set to reproduce it here.  reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for text you can using `text-align: center` for gain same distance in both direction but when you use `position` your element are dependent in `relative position` so for gain same distance you need to use `transform` property to manage it

use of `translate` CSS solve your problem.

```
.text {
    position:absolute;
    left: 500px;
    font-size:28px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing those position: absolute and left: 500px properties with
  "text-align: center" gives even spacing (in both directions) as the text grows..

```
<p contenteditable="true" class ="text">text</p>


.text
{
text-align: center;
font-size:28px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time, i got solution by other answers code as [here](http://139.59.24.243/ecom1/site/test/ni23)

Answer (score 0):

Then I think the following idea will work in this case... 
Modify the given width and max-height as per your need...

```css
.circle {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.textHolder {
  padding: 0 10px;
  width: 150px;
  max-height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  max-height: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <div class="textHolder">
    <p contenteditable="true" class="text">Type</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/wfbmyzuv/1/

Comment: While it is OK to post multiple answers if they are truly different, it may perhaps be better to edit the original one.  Note I made a snippet of your code so no need for the fiddler perhaps